# QTreeView: some cells editable

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I created a QTreeview(+QStandardItemModel(+QStandardItems)). On some cells I inserted a checkBox with by using setItemDelegate(). Now I want to set editable property, but all I try, nothing happens. I am wondering if setting flags hasn't any effect?

[image: eTreeView] [image]

Is there any method to set the both lower right items not editable and the both upper right items editable. At the moment I am also able to write to the both checkbox-items (next to the checkboxes) (when it loose focus, it will disappear and when making a screenshot i looses focus so I cant show you)

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to `return true` for indicating that event is handled in `QAbstractItemDelegate::editorEvent`